# Access network share from home computer connected with a VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, nas, cisco-anyconnect

I am trying to setup my home computer as a backup workstation I can use at home (I have cleared off all the legal questions with the management).

At work I have 5 network shares mounted. 4 on an internal server, and 1 which is a Synology NAS someone bought a long time ago to store some data one. On my work laptop I have a VPN (AnyConnect) which allows me to log in from home.

I have installed Anyconnect on my home workstation and when I connect to my work I can access the 4 network shares on the internal server. However, when I try to mount the Synology NAS it asks for a username and password. I have tried with my regular login but it doens't work. No one really knows what the login credentials should be since nobody has taken ownership of this NAS (It's obviously a small company).

When at home, and using the VPN, with my work laptop everything also just works - so what could possibly be the reason the NAS refuses my private workstation, but not my work laptop. Do you have any idea why my home desktop doesn't acquire the same rights as my laptop?

Comment: what OSs are involved, and what protocols are you using to access these shares (SMB, NFS, SSHFS/SFTP, etc)? is there a windows domain involved? if so, are both the laptop and desktop members of the same domain? are you connecting by IP or name?

Comment: @FrankThomas Good questions, should have clarified. Currently I am only testing with windows at the moment. I am accessing it by name, and I have no idea what protocol it uses - which I assume means windows just defaults to SMB. I am not sure if the the laptop and desktop are on the same domain, I assume something like this is the problem.

Comment: I'd try to confirm that the laptop and desktop are both domain members, and from the laptop, try to determine whether the syno box is on the domain. also, are both versions of windows the same?

Comment: Did you configure AnyConnect on the home workstation per the same guidelines the work laptop was configured from?  AnyConnect has a lot of configuration items, and I'd guess you just missed one.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that there are IP address restrictions configured on the NAS, such that only computers with an IP address on the internal network can access it, while the IP address range for VPN clients may be in a different range.

Comment: Thanks, but I am pretty sure that is not the case for various reasons. I have never had a problems getting access inside our networks (with a wide range of devices) and can get access using my work laptop using the VPN solution. To me I sound like a user-account problem.